# Can I do a Index and Match for Gsheet with more than 2 characters in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, vlookup

I need some help here.
Can do do a index and match if I have more than 2 character in cell?

I am getting NA when i used the index and match formula. I am not sure what is wrong is it due to more than 2 characters in the cell?

There are 2 Gsheets
I would like to lookup the 'Additional Notes' Column in Main Data Ghseet Tab to Extract  Gheet Tab - **Additional** Notes from Main Data.
Please help me on this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQQoRL0T8RrsAn3j3IXawVgiYXjpPwOHvL3JlL0vBGk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you?

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","", SIERREUR (JOIN(" - ", FILTER('Main Data'!B:B,REGEXMATCH('Main Data'!A:A,each)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2:A), TRIM('Main Data'!A:B), 2, )))
```

[image]